# Starting Debian mono application (that has a GUI) AFTER boot is done

Tags: debian, shell-script, cron, startup, rc

I've been trying to figure out how to start an application after Debian (Wheezy) is done booting up and on an LXDE desktop session. It is a mono C# application. The script I have is simply

```
mono /home/myapp/myapp.exe
```

I then added this script to init.d and from there did update-rc.d add myapp.
This did not work because it would return

```
(myapp:4820): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

As apparently not everything is yet set up to be able to use a GTK application. This is why I'd like to start the application AFTER everything has been set up. I've also tried adding it to crontab (-e) by adding this line:

```
@reboot /etc/init.d/myapp.sh
```

I've also added

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: beheertool
# Should-Start: console-screen dbus network-manager
# Required-Start: $all
# Required-Stop: $remote_fs 
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: start beheertool
### END INIT INFO
#
```

To the original script to perhaps make it launch later (with the Required-start: $all part).

None of these have worked, any help would greatly be appreciated.

**EDIT 1:** The application is a C# Mono application that uses GTK-sharp. 
The environment itself boots to a GUI (LXDE) without requiring login.
When normally running the application outside of the boot script X seems to be running (when checked with pidof X). Adding /usr/bin/startX to the script changed nothing, however.

Comment: What kind of Mono C# application is it? Please **edit your question** to tell much more about it... (if possible, give its source code, otherwise explain what it does and what are its dependencies). Do you have an Xorg server running when that C# app is started?

Comment: Can you provide use with some more information about this application? When are you expecting it to run - after a user logs in or at system boot? Does the system boot to a console login or does it boot to a graphical login? Does it even boot to a login requiring username and password? Those will help use understand how to reply and what to suggest...

Comment: It looks like your app requires a graphical server and, most probably, it has a graphical window when you start it. Have a look [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44288/run-gui-application-on-startup) for more details on auto starting GUI apps.

Comment: I've added to the question describing the situation a little more detailed, is more information required?

Comment: Have you tried on `rc.local`?

Comment: @jcbermu I have not, I can try it but the problem seems to be that the script is happening too early so GUIs cannot be called.

Comment: @Christopher I feel it is not a duplicate because the problem stems from something else and the solution of that question also does not apply to this case.

Comment: Indeed but the window manager differs in this case and as such the solution. I feel this question can be helpful in the future to someone else. If  you feel strongly that it is not it could be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Your asking for more information led me to finding out that the program had to be started **after** LXDE was ready for a desktop session.

And as such I googled and found out that **/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart** contains a list of applications that will be starting after the desktop session is started.

I added

```
@mono myapp.exe
```

And rebooted and it worked! Obviously this will only work on LXDE environments and so I will edit the question accordingly.